# _wp_old_slug is not working

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a post that its slug was changed from `google-photos` to `tips-google-photos`.
When i try to reach `www.example.com/2017/04/07/google-photos` it should be redirected to `www.example.com/2017/04/07/tips-google-photos` but it doesn't and it shows 404 page.
I went throughout my database and I did this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id=161154;
```

and found a `_wp_old_slug` meta_key with this value: `google-photos`. so the old slug is saved in database, but it seems something is wrong and worpress is not checking the old_slug value in database.

I'd appreciate if somebody can help me.

Comment: I've installed fresh wordpress (ver 4.7)

Answer (score -1):

It won't auto-redirect just by changing the slug (if you have links pointing to `.../google-photos`, just by updating the slug to `tips-google-photos` existing links in your site will still point to the original slug - that's why the 404). You can use a redirect plugin to solve the issue.

As for not being able to reach it directly under `.../tips-google-photos` - to regenerate the permalinks you have to visit `Settings > Permalinks` (no need to change anything, just hit `Save Changes` and this will force WP to regenerate all permalinks).

Please try and let me know if that fixed it.

Comment: I did regeneration before, and again now, but it's not working

Comment: when you edit the page/post in question, what URL is the page on?

Comment: the new one is showing, but the old one is not redirecting to new one.

Comment: WP does NOT autmatically redirect if you change the slug - why should it?
Use a plugin for it: [look here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)